# LuaTeX seems to not recognize any command

Tags: luatex

I am running ubuntu 20.4, with texlive-binaries (and texlive itelf) installed. I have several documents I managed to compile with XeTeX, but are supposed to be compiled with LuaTeX. I indeed have a luatex binary (v1.12), but it throws "Unrecognized control sequence" on the first line (basically `\newcommand{\example}{1}`).

I have constructed an MWE as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
example
\end{document}
```

which fails with output

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                {article}
```

Comment: you need to use `lualatex` with a latex document.

Comment: At least I can confirm that your code works on Overleaf (**LuaLaTeX**, TeXLive 2020).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: LuaTeX is to LuaLaTeX what PlainTeX is to LaTeX (or, these days, pdfLaTeX). To compile your test document, you need LuaLateX, *not* LuaTeX.

The first line of the log file that's produced when I compile your test document on my TeX system (MacTeX2021, w/ all updates applied) looks like this:

... pdfTeX (aka PlainTeX): `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdftex 2021.7.29)`

... pdfLaTeX (aka LaTeX): `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.22)`

... LuaTeX:  `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021) (format=luatex)`

... LuaLaTeX: `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021)  (format=lualatex)`

... XeTeX: `This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xetex 2021.9.22)`

... XeLaTeX: `This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.9.22)`

If the 'preloaded format' isn't either pdflatex, lualatex, or xelatex, your test program won't compile. In fact, the test program will crash on the very first instruction, *viz*., `\documentclass`. That's precisely what you report in your query. (Actually, you claim that compilation crashes on `\newcommand{\example}{1}`. A closer check, though, will reveal that LuateX crashes on `\documentclass`.)

Moral of the story? Be care to select an appropriate combination of TeX engine and format *before* trying to compile the document.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I was compiling it with XeLaTeX, not XeTeX, quite easy to be confused tbh.

The \newcommand was refering to the original document where I faced the issue, the log was for the MWE